# How can I consolidate this repetitive C# Code?

Tags: c#, iis, remote-access, remote-server

Essentially, my program is remoting to a server, stopping an app pool in IIS, copying a file, and finally restarting the app pool. I have to apply this same procedure to six different servers. How can I consolidate this into the simplest and most effective code?

Here is my code right now (Basically it's doing the same thing over, 6 times):

```
using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("RemoteServer1"))
{
    ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
        {
            appPool.Stop();
        }
    }

    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", @"\\RemoteServer1\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt");
    appPool.Start;
}



using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("RemoteServer2"))
{
    ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
        {
            appPool.Stop();
        }
    }

    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", @"\\RemoteServer2\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt");
    appPool.Start;
}



using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("RemoteServer3"))
{
    ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
        {
            appPool.Stop();
        }
    }

    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", @"\\RemoteServer3\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt");
    appPool.Start;
}



using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("RemoteServer4"))
{
    ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
        {
            appPool.Stop();
        }
    }

    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", @"\\RemoteServer4\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt");
    appPool.Start;
}



using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("RemoteServer5"))
{
    ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
        {
            appPool.Stop();
        }
    }

    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", @"\\RemoteServer5\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt");
    appPool.Start;
}



using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote("RemoteServer6"))
{
    ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
    if (appPool != null)
    {
        if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
        {
            appPool.Stop();
        }
    }

    File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", @"\\RemoteServer6\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt");
    appPool.Start;
}
```

Comment: by extracting a single method and provide the servers name as argument?

Comment: So, take what changes and create a function that takes them as variables, and then substitute them in the code above, put that into the method, and finally call the method 6 times with the different values.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything into a method that takes the server name as parameter

```
public void CopyFileToServer(string targetServerName)
{
    using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote(targetServerName)) 
    {
        ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
        if (appPool != null)
        {
            if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
            {
                appPool.Stop();
            }
        }

        // Depending on the Framework or Core version you might need to play
        // with the string interpolation for the second parameter
        File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", @$"\\{targetServerName}\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt");
    appPool.Start;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract one of these changes into a method, replacing the changes into parameters:

```
public void CopyToRemote(string remoteServer)
{
    using (ServerManager mgr = ServerManager.OpenRemote(remoteServer))
    {
        ApplicationPool appPool = mgr.ApplicationPools["TestAppPool"];
        if (appPool != null)
        {
            if (appPool.State == ObjectState.Started)
            {
                appPool.Stop();
            }
        }

        File.Copy(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Downloads\testfile.txt", string.Format(@"\\{0}\Users\TestUser\Documents\testfile.txt", remoteServer));
        appPool.Start;
    }
}
```

Call like:

```
for (int index = 1; index <= 6; index++)
{
    CopyToRemote($"RemoteServer{index}");
}
```